# Creating Console View in Eclipse-Kepler (RCP)

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am learning how to develop an RCP application. One of the tasks that I need to do is to create a console view. I have done some searching and I found the following code segment that supposedly creates a console view:

```
@PostConstruct
public void createComposite(Composite parent) {
    MessageConsole myConsole = findConsole("abc");// CONSOLE_NAME);
    MessageConsoleStream out = myConsole.newMessageStream();
    out.println("Hello from Generic console sample action");

    IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();
    String id = IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW;
    IConsoleView view = null;
    try {
        view = (IConsoleView) page.showView(id);
    } catch (PartInitException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    view.display(myConsole);
}

private MessageConsole findConsole(String name) {
    ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
    IConsoleManager conMan = plugin.getConsoleManager();
    IConsole[] existing = conMan.getConsoles();
    for (int i = 0; i < existing.length; i++)
        if (name.equals(existing[i].getName()))
            return (MessageConsole) existing[i];
    // no console found, so create a new one
    MessageConsole myConsole = new MessageConsole(name, null);
    conMan.addConsoles(new IConsole[] { myConsole });
    return myConsole;
}
```

But I keeping getting the following error:

> **org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.**

I tried to follow the suggestions posted in this article (http://waheedtechblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/javalangillegalstateexception-workbench.html), but to no avail.

My questions are the following:

1. What should be done in order to fix the above error?
2. Given the richness of Eclipse development environment, is there a better way of achieving the same thing with less programming effort (e.g. [Toggle the view of the Console in a RCP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194586/toggle-the-view-of-the-console-in-a-rcp-application))?

Comment: Where are you including all this code? From the error, you can tell it's not where it should be. Are you using e4? You should try other tutorials, btw.

Comment: For example: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t49690.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run existing Eclipse workbench code in a RCP you need to get the workbench setup properly in your application.

You can base your product definition on the existing `org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench` application:

```xml
<extension id="product" point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products"> 
  <product application="org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" name="name"/>
  ...
```

or you can call

```java
PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, advisor);
```

in your `IApplication` implementation, but you will have to do at least some of the work done by `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor` to get things to work properly.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the first solution? Also based on the following  quote (taken from http://waheedtechblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/javalangillegalstateexception-workbench.html) "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet

 This is essentially a race condition, and can be solved by either expressing an explicit dependency on that bundle or bumping up that bundle to a higher start level than the workbench. ",  My RCP is Eclipse 4 application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fproduct_def_extpt.htm

Comment: Here is the plugin.xml file. But I am still getting the same error?  Thanks!           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
id="product"
point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
name="com.lanterm.sigma"
  application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application">
<property
name="clearPersistedState"
value="true">
 </property>
 <property
name="applicationCSS"
               value="platform:/plugin/com.lanterm.sigma/css/default.css">
 </property>
<property
name="appName"
value="com.lanterm.sigma">
</property>
</product>
</extension>
</plugin>

Comment: You plugin.xml specifies the Eclipse e4 application - this does not support the workbench or consoles. If you want these you must use the old style `org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench` application.

Comment: Do you know therefore, of any pointers or links that describe how to have a console view for an Eclipse e4 Application? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: All I see are links saying there are plans to make some of these views work in future releases (maybe 4.4?).